# Работа с БД MS Access в С++

Tags: c++, база-данных, ms-access

Нужен совет каким образом сохранить список людей в БД. 
К примеру если использовать MS Access, что необходимо сделать для доступа к БД из C++ VS17? Какая из технологий (ADO,ODBC..) сейчас используется и где можно посмотреть примеры.

Comment: Любые популярные фреймворки .NET, Qt или работать с API типа ODBC. Примеры как всегда в учебниках или интернете.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770721/connect-to-ms-access-using-c

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал все таки использовать [ODBC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft-open-database-connectivity-odbc?view=sql-server-2017), так как он стандартизирован ISO и довольно прост в использовании. Например, вставка записей в БД MS Access осуществляется так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

WCHAR szDSN[] = L"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\users.mdb";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HENV    hEnv;
    HDBC    hDbc;

    /* ODBC API return status */
    RETCODE rc;

    int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
    WCHAR    szConnStrOut[256];

    WCHAR query[] = L"INSERT INTO [Users] (name,surname) VALUES ('Иван','Иванов');";

    HSTMT           hStmt;

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

    /* Connect to the database */
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN,
        SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut,
        255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {

        wprintf(L"Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n",
            szConnStrOut);

        /* Prepare SQL query */
        wprintf(L"SQL query:\n  %s\n", query);

        rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
        rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS);

        /* Excecute the query */
        rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
        {
            wprintf(L"SQL Success\n");
        }
        else {
            wprintf(L"SQL Failed\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s.\n", szDSN);
    }

    /* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Источник: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc811599(v=office.12)