# Как записывать данные с консоли на windows access с помощью C++

Tags: c++, ms-access

Хочу сделать программу которая будет записывать данные рабочих ан акссесс. Но не понимаю как сделать так что бы с++ делал эти действия. Помогите мне пожалуйста.

Comment: в акссессе есть вcтроенный язык visual basic. Если мне надо было что то автоматизировать там, то я в ту сторону копал бы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860645/Работа-с-БД-ms-access-в-С/863484#863484