# не могу подключить базу данных из access в qt

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt, ms-access, connect

[пользовался этим видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oK83ShQvlGs)

```
    QT       += core gui sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

mainwindow.h

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSqlDatabase db;
    QSqlTableModel *model;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC"); //драйвер
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=C:\\Users\\erohi\\Desktop\\dtbs.accdb");

    if (db.open())
    {
        qDebug("База данных открыта");
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("База данных закрыта");
    }

    model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
    model->setTable("Report");
    model->select();

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать! В чем собственно ошибка?

Comment: должно выводиться сообщение о том, что база данных подключена ("База данных открыта") и показывать ее, но вместо этого просто пишет "База данных закрыта"

Comment: Можно попробовать отладить строку соединения на чистом ODBC (см. тут пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860645/). Параметр FIL={MS Access} точно нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите что за ошибка возникает, от этого и пляшите..

```
if (db.open())
    {
        qDebug("База данных открыта");
    }
    else
    {
        // Для начала убедимся что драйвер QODBC присутствует в списке доступных
        qDebug()<<" we have this dirvers: "<<QSqlDatabase::drivers();
        // И посмотрим какая ошибка была при подключении (не забываем про #include <QSqlError>)
        qDebug()<<"and we get this error: "<<db.lastError().text();     

    }
```

Comment: we have this dirvers:  QList("QSQLITE", "QODBC", "QPSQL")
and we get this error:  "[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию QODBC: Unable to connect"

Comment: пробуйте изменять строку соединения и убедитесь в том что совпадает разрядность с разрядностью dsn